# Continuous build integration tool for Rails and PHP?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration

Most of "multi-platform" CI tools I've seen are in the Java/.NET world, like TeamCity or Hudson. Is there a continuous integration tool that can handle both PHP and Rails projects?

Answer (score 1):

Hudson is written in Java and is definitely Java-oriented, but it is sufficiently flexible to be useful in most environments. I've used it for .Net, raw C++, Qt projects with no problems. The general rule is that if it can be scripted then Hudson can do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is addons for CruiseControl for Ruby and PHP:

- http://cruisecontrolrb.thoughtworks.com/
- http://www.phpundercontrol.org/about.html

and Atlassian Bamboo can handle both too (but is not free):

- http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/features/requirements.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Instead of installing of your own platform you can use on-demand CI environment, like [fazend.com](http://www.fazend.com). It supports both RoR and PHP. Everything will depend on your build automation software.

Answer (score 1):

[Circle](https://circleci.com) is an [advanced CI service](https://circleci.com) with great support for Rails and PHP. It's hosted, has all the DBs and libraries that you need for PHP and Rails set up, and ready to use.

Most Rails projects can be set up in one click, and PHP projects can be [set up manually](https://circleci.com/docs/manually)

Joel and I spent a while chatting about this on the [Stackoverflow podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/se-podcast-22/) - [check it out](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/se-podcast-22/)!

Answer (score 0):

CruiseControl with phpUnderControl perfectly works together and do handles PHP projects but haven't tried using it with Rails.

It can do automatic uni tests, code analysis, and even auto deployment of projects.

http://topecoders.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-install-cruisecontrol.html